# How do i override the finalize() method of the class object itself?

Tags: java, class, java-threads, finalize

My problem is straightforward. I have a class that has a static `ThreadPoolExecutor` object. This threadpoolexecutor object is thus shared by all the instances of the class. If i were to shut the entire application down the shared class object would be garbage collected. I would like the threadpoolexecutor to be able to finish its pending jobs by calling `shutdown` on it and `awaitTermination` after that. This should be done in the `finalize()` method of the class object itself. My question is: How do i override the `finalize()` method of the class object itself? Is this even possible?

Thank you

Comment: Even if you did so, you have no guarantees that the GC will ever run. I would not recommend doing that shutdown there.

Comment: "*How do i override the finalize() method of the class object itself? Is this even possible?*" - No. No it is not. Even if it were, [`Object::finalize` is deprecated since Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()): "*The finalization mechanism is inherently problematic. Finalization can lead to performance issues, deadlocks, and hangs*". Just don't do it.

Comment: It's worth noting that a `Class` isn't eligible for collection until its `ClassLoader` also is.

Comment: ok so is there another way to achieve this then?

Comment: There is nothing about garbage collection that will interrupt running jobs or cause them not to finish. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`finalize()` is really not recommended as it's not reliable. However, you could benefit from using `JVM ShutdownHooks`. Access your static pool inside the hook and attempt to do your cleanup.

Example Usage:

```
public class ShutdownTest {

    static PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        writer.println("Application Started");
        writer.flush();

        Thread.sleep(2000);

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() ->{
            writer.println("Application shutdown started");
            writer.println("Closing resource");
            writer.close();
        }));

    }
}
```

Comment: Shutdown hooks should not engage in long or blocking operations. See the Javadoc.